# Comparing two files using Awk

Tags: linux, parsing, unix, text, awk

I have two text files one with a list of ids and another one with some id and corresponding values.

File 1

```
abc
abcd
def
cab
kac
```

File 2

```
abcd   100
def    200
cab    500
kan    400
```

So, I want to compare both the files and fetch the value of matching columns and also keep all the id from File 1 and assign "NA" to the ids that don't have a value in File2

Desired output

```
abc     NA
abcd    100
def     200
cab     500
kac     NA
```

PS: Only Awk script/One-liners

The code I'm using to print matching columns:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++;next}a[$1]{print $1,"\t",$2}'
```

Comment: So, what did you try?

Comment: I was only able to print the matching values.

Comment: Please add that code to your question.

Comment: @JamesBrown Added

Comment: Is it important to keep the order of file1?

Comment: @rudimeier not that important, but all of them should be included on the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {print $1,  ($1 in a? a[$1]: "NA") }' file2 file1
abc NA
abcd 100
def 200
cab 500
kac NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `join` and `sort` (hopefully portable):

```
export LC_ALL=C
sort -k1 file1 > /tmp/sorted1
sort -k1 file2 > /tmp/sorted2
join -a 1 -e NA -o 0,2.2 /tmp/sorted1 /tmp/sorted2
```

In bash you can use here-files in a single line:

```
LC_ALL=C join -a 1 -e NA -o 0,2.2 <(LC_ALL=C sort -k1 file1) <(LC_ALL=C sort -k1 file2)
```

Note 1, this gives output sorted by 1st column:

```
abc NA
abcd 100
cab 500
def 200
kac NA
```

Note 2, the commands may work even without LC_ALL=C. Important is that all sort and join commands are using the same locale.